# How to pull new files and changes with git without commiting my changes?

Tags: git, version-control, github

Is there a way to use git to pull new files and changes that others have made, without having to commit my changes? I'm fearful that my changes might mess things up..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you can use `git fetch` anytime to load the changes from the remote repository without it influencing your working directory or your local branches at all.

What you probably want is to stash your changes, so you can update your local branch to the newest state, and then continue working on your changes. To do that, use `git stash`. This will save your changes temporarily and then *revert* them, so it looks as if you did not do anything (don’t worry, it’s still saved). Then you can just `git pull` to update your branch and get the newest changes. After that, use `git stash pop` to unstash your changes, and get them back.

In some cases, you will run into conflicts when unstashing things, usually when you started editing files that were also changed in the updates from `git pull`. Those files get the usual conflict markers and you can resolve them locally just as you are used to.

Comment: `git stash -u` to include untracked files too. Although since branches are so cheap, I just make a new branch with `git checkout -b wip-security-experiment`, for exapmyle. You can then merge that in later, rebase it, cherry-pick, whatever! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can stash (hide) your changes, pull and then apply your changes again:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop # or apply if you want to keep the changes in the stash
```

Note that if there are any conflicts, `git stash pop` will fail and you will have to resolve them.